# ews-java-api - cant set instance of class

Tags: java, web-services, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

im trying to develop ews-java-api simple program.
i am following [the guide](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/wiki/Getting-Started-Guide) and it shows how to set an ExchangeService variable name "service".

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("emailAddress", "password");
service.setCredentials(credentials);
```

i've made it and it's all good.

then it shows how to create a message variable class, under the title "sending a message"

```
EmailMessage msg= new EmailMessage(service);
msg.setSubject("Hello world!");
msg.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("Sent using the EWS Java API."));
msg.getToRecipients().add("someone@contoso.com");
msg.send();
```

my program won't accept it.
i get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Unhandled exception type Exception

    at project2.liran.main(liran.java:19)
```

here is my program as i wrote it:

```
package project2;

import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.enumeration.misc.ExchangeVersion;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.Appointment;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.EmailMessage;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.credential.ExchangeCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.credential.WebCredentials;
import java.net.*;


public class liran {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("emailAddress", "password");
    service.setCredentials(credentials);
    URI uri = URI.create ("http://www.cnn.com");
    service.setUrl(uri);
    EmailMessage msg= new EmailMessage(service);
    }

}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly as the error message states. In line no 19, the Checked Exception is not handled. The Constructor for `EmailMessage` has `throws Exception` clause and so your program must handle it.

This is the constructor:

```
 public EmailMessage(ExchangeService service) throws Exception {
    super(service);
  }
```

Reference : [Github Repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/microsoft/exchange/webservices/data/core/service/item/EmailMessage.java)

I would advise you to go with an IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ IDEA) for your development.

Visit Oracle's [Exception Handling](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) for more information.